# How to get the difference equation from second-order digital filter block diagram?

Tags: signal-processing, signal, digital-communication

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here I have a diagram  and I am trying to create a difference equation for the filter.

I've been using practice examples to try figure this one out however I am unable to produce a complete difference equation;

For example;

```
  x[n] ---| A |---+---| B |--- y[n]
          z ^-1   |   z ^-1
                  |
                  +---| C |
                      z ^-1
```

where x[n] is the input signal, y[n] is the output signal, and A, B, and C are blocks with transfer functions:

A: H1(z) = (1 + 2z^-1 + z^-2) / (1 + 0.5z^-1)
B: H2(z) = (1 - z^-1) / (1 - 0.8z^-1)
C: H3(z) = (1 + z^-1) / (1 + 0.9z^-1 + 0.2z^-2)\

Block A: input = x[n], output = a[n]
Block B: input = a[n-1], output = b[n]
Block C: input = b[n-1], output = y[n] 
Step 3: Write down the equations for each block.\

Block A: a[n] = H1(z)x[n] + 0.5a[n-1] - 0.5a[n-2] - H1(z)z^-1x[n]
Block B: b[n] = H2(z)a[n-1] + 0.8b[n-1] - H2(z)z^-1a[n-1]
Block C: y[n] = H3(z)b[n-1] - 0.9y[n-1] - 0.2y[n-2] + H3(z)z^-1b[n-1]\

Step 4: Combine the equations for all blocks to obtain the overall system equation.

Substituting the equation for a[n] into the equation for b[n], and the equation for b[n] into the equation for y[n], we get:

y[n] = H3(z)H2(z)(H1(z)x[n] + 0.5H1(z)z^-1x[n-1] - 0.5H1(z)z^-2x[n-2] - 0.8a[n-1] + H2(z)z^-1a[n-1]) - 0.9y[n-1] - 0.2y[n-2]

Step 5: Use the z-transform to convert the system equation into a difference equation.

**etc.. This is how I would usually approach this type of question; However I can't quite figure this one out. Would someone be able to give me the answer so I can reverse engineer this or at least put me along the right track! Thank you so much :)**

Comment: Are you asking for help with the first diagram or the ASCII art diagram? The ASCII art diagram appears misaligned to me. Can you double check?

Comment: Im asking for help with the diagram, the ascii art is something quick I drew , it isn't going to be perfect but just to showcase my working for example

Comment: Does the diagram correspond to one of the four forms mentioned [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter#Direct_form_2)?

Comment: Tried to tidy your ascii graphics feel free to revert back. Arrowheads would be nice.